# Executing a scope bound function with parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I have a function like this in a directive:

```
 scope: {
      loadChildren: "&"
 },
```

How can I call this from my controller and pass parameters?

```
$scope.loadChildren(param1, param2);
```

My directive executes the function I pass it but I don't see any parameters.

Is there any way to pass them like this?

**EDIT re: rodyhaddad's answer**

rodyhaddad points the way and gives the correct format for passing parameters to a bound function. However, in order to get it working I also had to add the parameter keys into my HTML like this:

```
<example load-children="load(param1, param2)"></example>
```

Then on my controller I can see parameters:

```
$scope.load = function (param1, param2) {
    debugger;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```js
  loadChildren: "&"
```

This is the code that generates the function ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1003-L1008))

```js
case '&': {
  parentGet = $parse(attrs[attrName]);
  scope[scopeName] = function(locals) {
    return parentGet(parentScope, locals);
  };
  break;
```

So as you can see, whatever you pass to `loadChildren` will become the `locals` passed to `$parse`.

So the correct way to call it would be:

```js
$scope.loadChildren({
  param1: param1,
  param2: param2
});
```

If you want another example, here's how event directives (like `ngClick`) expose `$event` to their expressions: [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L48)

Comment: In order to get this to work I also had to add the parameters in the HTML - see my edit.

Comment: What about when the parameter is ALSO a function?